# How to get an evm reference inside go-ethereum GetBalance function?

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, golang

In order to modify GetBalance function to fork go-ethereum, I find difficulties to get a reference of the running **evm**. The function has a reference for self *StateDB:

```
func (self *StateDB) GetBalance(addr common.Address) *big.Int
```

but I cannot get an evm of type *vm.EVM from StateDB. I need the **evm** to make a contract call inside the GetBalance function for this fork. Is it possible in some way to get the evm from StateDB, or should I use any other strategy?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to execute a smart contract from GetBalance? I think you can call GetBalance outside the EVM so you wont be able to get the running instance of the EVM in that case.

Comment: Yes, I want GetBalance to call a SC whenever it is run. So I don't want to call GetBalance, but to force a SC call when go-ethereum calls GetBalance. This is why I need an EVM reference inside GetBalance scope.

Answer (score 1):

getBalance `doesn't require EVM` because it only reads data in StateDB.

Therefore, it is in core/state/statedb.

I recommend creating a new instruction.

and reference **other instructions changing stateDB.**

for example, opStaticCall in core/vm/instruction

```
func opStaticCall(pc *uint64, interpreter *EVMInterpreter, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error)
```

this function calls staticCall in core/vm/evm

```
func (evm *EVM) StaticCall(caller ContractRef, addr common.Address, input []byte, gas uint64) (ret []byte, leftOverGas uint64, err error)
```

this function include this line

```
evm.StateDB.AddBalance(addr, bigZero)
```

Comment: Sorry but, this solution wouldn't allow to invoke contract call from inside getBalance, and there is where I need it to be. opStaticCall requires an interpreter *EVMInterpreter parameter I still don't have inside getBalance function.